# How to get a Get a Request Token from Yahoo api in PHP?

Tags: php, symfony, oauth, yahoo-api

I'm trying to make an invitation function in my website and I decided to start by Yahoo. After registering my app, I have trouble obtaining a Request Token from Yahoo api. I tried the URL with wget and I get this answer even with the right oauth_signature.

```
wget -S -d 'https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_request_token?oauth_nonce=-----------------------------&oauth_consumer_key=------------------------------------------------------------&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_signature="-----------------------------&"&oauth_version=1.0&xoauth_lang_pref="en-us"&oauth_callback=oob'
```

Note that I added a "&" at the end of oauth_signature as the Yahoo documentation asks here: [Yahoo API Documentation](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-signing.html#oauth-sign-hmac)

And I get:

```
---response begin---
HTTP/1.1 401 Forbidden
Date: Sat, 25 Jul 2015 19:05:58 GMT
P3P: policyref="http://info.yahoo.com/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="CAO DSP COR CUR ADM DEV TAI PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi TELo OTPi OUR DELi SAMi OTRi UNRi PUBi IND PHY ONL UNI PUR FIN COM NAV INT DEM CNT STA POL HEA PRE LOC GOV"
WWW-Authenticate: OAuth oauth_problem=signature_invalid
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 31
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Age: 0
Connection: close
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000
Server: ATS

---response end---
```

Does anyone knows what I do wrong?

--Edit
I'm not sure of the way the oauth_signature is generated, I tried what is indicated there [Yahoo API Documentation](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-signing.html#oauth-sign-hmac) but it doesn't work.

Comment: I finally use plaintext as oauth_signature_method waiting to find how to sign requests with HMAC-SHA1.